# Do Shrines affect Followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

I always assumed they did (your follower runs as fast as you after you trigger a Fleeting Shrine). However, I noticed that my follower's damage did not increase (whereas mine did) after I triggered a Frenzied Shrine.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the follower probably is just inheriting player's run speed specifically. They always keep up, whatever run speed the player has currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, shrines have no effect on followers. Legendary gems also do not work with followers either.

Comment: Do you have a source/reference?

Comment: There isn't much documentation regarding shrines and followers, but if you've played for long enough you know they have no effect.

Comment: Can confirm what infek says. Legendary gems don't work - that information is not in-game, but displayed on the wiki and under the legendary gems section. Shrines have no effect because you can see followers not get the conduit or attack speed shrines.